# collecting output and form submission on a different page?

Tags: javascript, forms, macros, submission, imacros

I'm looking for a way to gather the output(in text) on a webpage after a form submission.

Is there a way to maybe see the http response of a form submission in Javscript?

Otherwise, I would like to know if there's a nice way to somehow, say parse or collect outputs of multiple webpage(same page) form submissions. I know it's not possible (or too complicated) to save a file with the output in Firefox using Javascript.

So an option for me is to set up another webpage that will accept form submissions and somehow output the http response or webpage after submitting a form on a different page.

I was trying to do all this in Greasemonkey but I can't figure out a way to collect the output of multiple form submissions(of the same page) for analysis after finishing. What I have so far is filling out the right form and submitting(though it seems to keep going in a loop forever because every time you submit the form you land back on the same page and the Greasemonkey script executes the form submission over and over again), but I'm stumped at how to somehow collect the results.

I have not used macros like iMacros before so perhaps that might be a more suitable approach?

Thanks! Open to any suggestions and hope to hear any help! Muchhhh appreciated! :) Thanks again!

Comment: I think an AJAX request could do the job. It can send a HTTP request using both GET and POST, and when it's done you have access to the response.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I am unfamiliar with AJAX, have not had any experience before, are you willing to provide just a simple GET request and response in a simple example? Would I be writing such code in Greasemonkey?

Answer (score 0):

I've not any experience with Greasymonkey, but an AJAX call is relatively easy when using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) (but I don't know whether jQuery works with Greasemonkey).

http://jsfiddle.net/9peGW/

```
$.ajax({ url: "/",
         type: "GET",
         data: $('#theform').serialize(), // returns like '?test=val&test2=val2'
                                          // using the elements of the form
         success: function(text, state, xhr) {
           alert(text.substring(0, 200));
             // alert first 200 response characters
             // (so that it fits in the alert box)
           alert(xhr.getResponseHeader("Content-Type"));
             // alert the Content-Type response header
         }
      });
```

Note though that AJAX requests only work for the same domain as it is called from, but perhaps this is not applicable through Greasymonkey (I really don't have experience with that).

Answer (score 0):

İt is too easy at İmacros. You can search for a tag and extract information that you need. Do not try jQuery. It is too complicated for this job, I know :)